# Вывод фотографии в записи

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. Совсем недавно начал знакомиться с Wordpress и озадачился одним вопросом. На главной странице выводится афиша ближайших мероприятий. При клике на мероприятие открывается его полное описание. В этом описании есть блок фотографий и он индивидуальный для каждого поста, т.е. в каждом мероприятии свои фотографии. Как это можно реализовать? Цикл в цикле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как это можно реализовать?

[Произвольные поля](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F) или готовые плагины для нескольких изображений записи. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-featured-image/